# Does Tails OS have binary blobs in its kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, binary, proprietary-drivers, tails-os

Or is the kernel 100% open source?

Comment: its is open source Debian-based.

Comment: @AvinashRedy I know it's Debian based and that the vast majority of its source code is released. But even Debian has binary blobs, I think? Or does Debian use  the "Linux Libre" kernel?

Comment: yes it include non-free firmware

Comment: @AvinashRedy If you can find a source for that, then you could post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the link for your [binary blobs](https://tails.boum.org/contribute/design/#index1h1).

Quote from the link:

> Binary firmware blobs from the Debian non-free archive are installed
>   when no good Free Software alternative exists.